# Nginx location to match query parameters

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

Is it possible in nginx to have a `location {...}` block that matches query parameters. For example I want to pick up that `preview=true` in URL below and then instruct it to do several different things, all possible in a location block.

```
http://192.158.0.1/web/test.php?hello=test&preview=true&another=var
```

The problem I'm having is that my test stuff doesn't seem to match, it seems like I can only match the URL itself?

E.g.

```
location ~ ^(.*)(preview)(.*)$
```

Or something aloong those lines?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: To match preview=true in the url in order to disable caching in the location (as location / caches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`proxy_cache_bypass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass) directive.

```
proxy_cache_bypass $arg_preview;
```

Comment: This is correct; thanks Michael. Unfortunately it's not possible to match arguments in a location {} block though

Comment: You shouldn't be using a separate `location` block at all. If this doesn't work with your existing directives, you've probably found a bug in nginx.